# Output getting altered/truncated from message queue

Tags: c, multithreading, message-queue

I'm trying to get the hang of message queues. For some reason, when displaying the message I typed back into the console, the string sometimes gets truncated, or altered. Does anyone know why this might be occuring?

```
void *readFromQueue() {
    int ret;
    mbr = malloc(sizeof(struct msgbuf)); // Allocate space to mbr.
    while (TRUE) { // Forever...
        ret = (int) msgrcv(msgId, mbr, sizeof(struct msgbuf), myId, MSG_NOERROR | IPC_NOWAIT); // Receive a message 
        if (ret == -1) { // Check for error.
            //perror("Failed to receive message.");
        } else {
            printf("\t%160s", mbr->mtext);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is `char mtext[1];` a typo for `char mtext[160];`?

Comment: @Bob__ I made that change, but I am still getting the strange errors.

Comment: `mtype` should be a `long`, not an `int`.  See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/msgrcv.html and http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/msgsnd.2.html

Comment: @AndrewHenle That fixed a different error i was working through, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that my bug was in my passing of the size of the struct msgbuf instead of the size of msgbuf.mtext.

```
 ret = msgrcv(msgId, mbr, sizeof(mbr->mtext), myId, MSG_NOERROR | IPC_NOWAIT);
```